# Python get web page screenshot color palette

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am using Python 2.7 to try to get 5-color palette from screenshots of web pages.

The methods I have tried so far are not producing satisfactory results.

The palettes converge on a greens, grays and blues when web pages have other maybe not dominant but thematically important colors that should be in a palette.

A sample of output is included here. I have put a 5 cell table above each image thumbnail, each showing one of the 5 colors.

[image]

My code with methods commented out is below but to summarize I have been using `Pillow` and a promising module called `colorthief`.

I think that most of these color palette exercises work on photograph or graphics of scenes and objects which are full of colors give or take. Web pages are different. They have loads of white space and black text.

The best results, though far from satisfactory, were a method that changed white  pixels to transparent. This allowed a few screenshots to exhibit palettes with more than blue, gray, greens.

I suspect that if I could remove all white and black pixels from screenshot first, and perhaps all other pixels within a related % to white and black (eg off-whites, dark grays) then I the palette could be generated from set of pixels with just colors.

Web search hasn't revealed any techniques specifically dealing with web page or document palette generation.

I might have to rethink palette generation and get it from HTML directly. But want to try to make the image method work if possible.

So the question is how can I get color palette from a screenshot of a web page that excludes white, black and is based on only colors in image?

```
import os, os.path
from PIL import Image
import psycopg2
from colorthief import ColorThief

conn_string = \
    "host='localhost' \
    dbname='databasename' \
    user='username' \
    password='password'" 

conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)     
cur = conn.cursor()

## dev paths
screenshots_path = 'path/to/screenshots/'

screenshots_dir = os.listdir(screenshots_path)
for screenshot in screenshots_dir:
    if screenshot != 'Thumbs.db':

        try:
            img_orig = Image.open(screenshots_path + screenshot)

             ## method 1 replace white pixels with transparent
            # img = img_orig.convert("RGBA")
            # datas = img.getdata()
            # newData = []
            # for item in datas:
                # if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
                    # newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
                # else:
                    # newData.append(item)
            # img.putdata(newData)

            ## method 2 - pillow 
            img = img_orig.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=5)  
            width, height = img.size
            height = img.size[1]
            quantized = img.quantize(colors=5, kmeans=3)
            palette = quantized.getpalette()[:15]
            convert_rgb = quantized.convert('RGB')
            colors = convert_rgb.getcolors(width*height)
            color_str = str(sorted(colors, reverse=True))
            color_str = str([x[1] for x in colors])
            print screenshot + ' ' + color_str


        ## method 3 - colorthief
        # try:
            # img = Image.open(screenshots_path + screenshot)
            # color_thief = ColorThief(screenshots_path + screenshot)
            ## get the dominant color
            # dominant_color = color_thief.get_color(quality=1)
            # build a color palette
            # color_str = color_thief.get_palette(color_count=5)
            # print screenshot + ' ' + str(height) + ' ' + str(color_str)


            cur.execute("UPDATE screenshots set color_palette = %s, height = %s WHERE filename like %s", (str(color_str), height, '%' + screenshot + '%',))
            conn.commit()

        except:
            continue

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're so mathematically inclined, by you might want to read this tutorial on [finding dominant colors in an image](http://aishack.in/tutorials/dominant-color/). The idea is to use statistics of the image colors to figure out the color palette. You start out with a single "main" color - the average color of the entire image. Then you break this color into two components, and then three and so on. The code lets you decide how many colors you want to extract.

Here's a result I got using the code mentioned on the website:

[image: Finding dominant colors of a screenshot]

Comment: That link was good and got me looking in right direction. Pretty straightforward with opencv. Found another [blog post] (http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/05/26/opencv-python-k-means-color-clustering/) that has something like this implemented in Python and it works fine.

Comment: Btw to interested readers, my original solution was actually working. It was producing similar results to those shown by Utkarsh & on the pyimagesearch link above. I was getting blue / green colors because I was using wrong inline style HTML reference in the table background color where I was showing colors (one in each td). I was using `bgcolor="rgb(232, 147, 31)"` instead of `style="background-color: rgb(232, 147, 31)"` Browsers do not like `bgcolor` inline only in css. But glad I dug into opencv though.